# Android 4.x NoClassDefFoundError with Multidex fully implemented

Tags: android, android-multidex

I recently added another dependency to my app which pushed it over the 64k limit and required Multidex. When running on Android 4.x the app now crashes on startup with a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.naturenet.debug, PID: 3136
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.naturenet.util.ForestFire
at org.naturenet.NatureNetApplication.onCreate(NatureNetApplication.java:60)
```

Other cases of this error suggest that it is because Multidex is not fully implemented, but this still happens with all of the following changes:

**app build file**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    ...
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.naturenet"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
            additionalParameters('jack.incremental': 'true')
        }
    }
}
```

**Application class**

```
public class NatureNetApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
```

The ForestFire class in question has not changed. I originally had different implementations under the debug and release source trees, but replacing those with a single file in the main source tree made no difference.

Comment: have you tried to clean and run again... or turn off the instant run from the preferences ??

Comment: Yes I have done full rebuilds and installed to fresh devices. I am not using instant run.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39841778/213156 but since the proposed workaround from the bug page isn't working for me I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you seen [those instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep)? Can you tell whether or not `org.naturenet.util.ForestFire` class placed in main-dex (a.k.a. classes.dex)? If it does, then the problem probably happens because one of the classes that `org.naturenet.util.ForestFire` depends on: in this case run on 4.x device again and look for log entries with dalvikvm tag (particularly with DexOpt or VFY substrings). Do you see anything relevant?

Comment: @AlexLipov I hadn't, thanks. I've backed out of Java 8 and Jack, and it's working now with Multidex so I assume it was related to the legacy bug, but I'll try that too.

Comment: No need to add `additionalParameters('jack.incremental': 'true')` as it's enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue on Android 4.* devices and it somehow was connected with using Jack toolchain.

But [Jack was deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html) and Android Studio 2.4 Preview 6 was released:

> Java 8 language features are now supported by the Android build system
>   in the javac/dx compilation path. Android Studio's Gradle plugin now
>   desugars Java 8 class files to Java 7-compatible class files, so you
>   can use lambdas, method references and other features of Java 8.

See [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/java-8-language-features-support-update.html) for more info.

Now you can install [Android Studio Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) and remove `jackOptions` from `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your manifest in case you haven't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

For more info : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=en-419

Comment: The problem is occurring in my custom Application class which extends MultiDexApplication. It was already specified in the manifest.